# How does recursion work when there are two recursive calls in a same statement?

Tags: c++, recursion, fibonacci

I have recently taken up studying algorithms and data structures.I came across fibonacci problem and its solution using recursion. But thats the thing. I understand how recursive calls work when there is only one(like in factorial of a number).The function calls keep on stacking up until they hit the base case and then they start unraveling  by one to the desired answer.

But What I dont get is how does recursion work when there are two recursive calls in an expression like f(n)+f(n/2). I mean which call is resolved first and when does the second call gets resolved. Also how is the sum calculated if this expression is assigned to a statement?
 I wrote a small code to decipher this myself.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


int main()
{
  int recursionTest(int n, char c);
  int x;
  std::cin>>x;
  std::cout<<"Ans:"<<recursionTest(x,'c');

}


int recursionTest(int n,char c)
{
   int result=0;
   if(n==0)
    return 1;
   std::cout<<n<<":"<<c<<std::endl;
   result=recursionTest(n/2,'L')+recursionTest(n/3,'R');////I cant figure 
                                                           out the flow of 
                                                           control here!!!
   return result;
}
```

And I got the following output.

```
24
24:c
12:L
6:L
3:L
1:L
1:R
2:R
1:L
4:R
2:L
1:L
1:R
8:R
4:L
2:L
1:L
1:R
2:R
1:L
Ans:20
```

SO I get it ,its a tree structure. But I still dont know how we are getting 20 as answer(input=24). How is the sum expression working and what is it summing,how can I look at the tree structure and generate the same out put?

[image: Binary Tree representation of output]

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order

Comment: I'll defenitely look into the link . But from what I've read, thats not what my confusion is. I wanted to know if the left expression keeps on unraveling after hitting the base case, during that time the right expression stats as it is ? If so then when does the right part starts unraveling its stacked function calls?

Answer (score 2):

There is no defined order to how the two subexpressions of the `+` operator are evaluated. The compiler can emit code to evaluate either one first and the other one second. It can even interleave some computations of one side with computations of the other. For example, it could calculate `n/3`, then `n/2`, then the right function call, and finally the left function call.

The flow control is just like for a single case of recursion followed by another single case. So, your line:

```
result=recursionTest(n/2,'L')+recursionTest(n/3,'R');
```

is effectively the same as:

```
int left = recursionTest(n/2,'L');
int right = recursionTest(n/3,'R');
result = left + right;
```

except for the implication in my version that the left function call is guaranteed to be evaluated before the right function call.

Comment: Okay, when you write left+right, what is the stacking order of the calls? first int left=() gets stacked till exhausted, then int right=() gets stacked till exhausted, in the third line left+right, how is this evaluated? who gets executed first?

Comment: The third line is just simple addition of two `int`s. The evaluation is to just add the numbers. In all probability, it's a single instruction. There's no order of evaluation question regarding that statement.

Comment: How is the answer coming 20? By this logic it should be the sum of whole tree ryt?

Comment: In your graph, you have ① nodes as leaves, but that isn't right. If `recursionTest()` is called with 1, it will go to the recursive statement. There will be two ⓪ child nodes for each ① node. Only ⓪ nodes can be leaves. Also, each non-leaf must always have two children, because the recursive statement always makes two recursive calls. Only one of your ② nodes has a ⓪ child node. They all should have them. The sum will be the count of ⓪ leaf nodes in the tree (because only ⓪ nodes contribute a "new" amount to the sum and that amount is always 1).

Answer (score -1):

Here operator precedence will play the role

```
f(n) + f(n/2);
```

In the above code snippet f(n) will get called first and then f(n/2). basically arithmetic operators compile from left to right.
If you want to debug the code use printf statements inside function f(int) by printing n value . By this you can get the hang of the code

Comment: There is no guarantee that `f(n)` will be called before `f(n/2)`. The compiler is free to call either one first.

Comment: If you have doubts read the link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ktz6ya2s.aspx

Comment: There is nothing in the link to indicate that `f(n)` will be evaluated before `f(n/2)`. Don't confuse left to right associativity with left to right order of evaluation.